# Dilemma between "which" and "that"

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, that-vs-which

Are the words in bold interchangeable in this context?

> A network is a set of computers that are connected to each other so that information can be shared or sent to one computer to another. It is a global system of interconnected computer networks **that**/**which** links device worldwide.

I do not know whether to use *which* or *that*, or are they interchangeable?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be 'devices' in plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the correct choice is "that". The extract begins talking about "a network", which could be a connection between as few as two computers. The purpose of that sentence is to define the word "network". The next sentence builds on that definition to introduce the idea of a much wider system of networks, one which connects computers worldwide. Consider the sentence

> **It** is a global system of interconnected computer networks that links devices worldwide.

The meaning of the sentence is

> That which connects computers worldwide is a global system of networks.

The referent of the word "it" is not the "network" defined in the previous sentence, but a network "which connects computers worldwide."

If the word "which" is used instead, the word "it" might be taken as referring to the simple "network" previously defined.